# Can the AWS IOT Broker be installed on local server for testing AWS IOT Client

Tags: aws-iot

I have coded my IOT client device using AWS IOT Client SDK in Embedded C wherein the SDK is free. Later i came to know that AWS IOT Broker which is in AMAZON cloud is not a free service, there is limit for certain amount of messages per month.
I am looking for a solution is it possible to get the AWS IOT Broker installer for free, so that i can host the AWS IOT Broker on my local server and use it? so i need not to pay for AWS IOT Cloud services. Does we have this option or we have to compulsory use the AMAZON AWS IOT Cloud services only(which is not free)?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS IOT cloud offering from Amazon is not available for installation on a local server.

As you are already using what I assume to be the [AWS IoT Device SDK for embedded C](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C) you are already tied to AWS IOT.

If you only need pub/sub capabilities and MQTT there a number of free MQTT based offerings that you can install on a local server.

You'll loose out on AWS specific services such as Thing Shadow.